# to manipulate a character with php

Tags: php, regex

I need to manipulate a string that has a special caratectere (`em dash`), I have this string in a variable `alta. —  The ambient temperature is quite high` and in no way can I use the `explode` from it, either with `explode ('-', $ str)` or using `chr('-')`, I just need to have it as a point to apply my logic but I can not

here is how it is displayed in html
[image: ""]

the way it is displayed in the DOM:

[image]

Here I looped to display each letter in a line followed by the unicode with `ord($str)`

[image]

Here is the code I used to display a letter on each line and get that black character that I have no idea whatsoever

```
for($i = 0; $i<= strlen($str); $i++) {
    echo"<br>";
            echo ord($str[$i]);
            echo"<br>";
            echo $str[$i];
}
```

I want to get the index of this character in the string or simply use the `explode` method from this character

Comment: It is not clear to me what it is that you are asking.  Please clearly state what it currently is doing and what you want it to do.

Comment: First read: [What every programmer absolutely, positively needs to know about encodings and character sets to work with text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/). Then [mb_* string funcs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) in the manual. Also why is this tagged `regex`, but no trace of its usage yet? And why not explain what the concrete task is?

Comment: @mario regex can be a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I do to that "stuff"

```
$search = array(
        "\xe2\x80\x98", // "'"
        "\xe2\x80\x99", // "'"
        "\xe2\x80\x9c", // '"'
        "\xe2\x80\x9d", // '"'
        "\xe2\x80\x93", // '-'
        "\xe2\x80\x94", // '-'
        "\xe2\x80\xa6", // '...'
        chr(145),
        chr(146),
        chr(147),
        chr(148),
        chr(150),
        chr(151),
        chr(133)    
    );

    $replace = array(
        "'",
        "'",
        '"',
        '"',
        '-',
        '-',
        '...',
        "'",
        "'",
        '"',
        '"',
        '-',
        '-',
        '...'
    );

    $text = str_replace($search, $replace, $text);
```

Nothing but a headache.  Probably pasted from MSWord or such.

Test it:

```
 $text = 'alta. —  The ambient temperature is quite high';

 echo $text."\n";

 //... the above code ...

 echo $text."\n";
```

Output

```
alta. —  The ambient temperature is quite high
alta. -  The ambient temperature is quite high
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cb030cc032a86d795c0eaef3ded25f6d77725f6f)

Normally I just make a function somewhere, throw that stuff into it and clean it up.  Then it's a normal `-` hyphen and everything works as expected.

I made this like 7 or 8 years ago, still use it.  It's like `MSWIN1252` charset or such.

Comment: I'm getting the same output ...
will this be because I use utf8 default?

Comment: I realized that if I copy the string from here it works, how bizarre

Comment: no ... it's magic!  Pretty sure these have to be double quotes `"\xe2\x80\x98"`  it's like `"\n"`